# Как удалить поля в админ форме Django?

Tags: python, django

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    def _active(self):
        if self.active:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Подскажите, как в админке удалить поле some_field только для тех объектов, у которых _active возвращает True?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, obj):
        if obj._active:
            return ['name', 'active']
        return ['name', 'active', 'some_field']
```

Comment: А если я использую fieldsets, как это сделать посредством get_fieldsets?

Comment: Все разобрался. Спасибо!